# Can I prepare trigger action in Choreograph for Pepper?

Tags: webhooks, pepper, choregraphe

I'm looking for solution, how to solve a problem with Pepper and Choreograph. If this is not possible by Choreograph, I will gladly use it anyway.
I have a screen (not a tablet),which can be trigged using a webhook. This webhook has options to enable and disable that screen. I would like Pepper to say something and then he turned on screen and said something and turned it off. How to solve it in Choreographe? If not in Choreograhe, someone could help with advice / code.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

If you screen can be trigged by a webhook, just access the screen from pepper.

A simple way (but not efficient): in a python box, enter this code, for instance in the onStart method:

```
import os
os.system( "wget your_web_adress" )
```

Once you validate it works, consider using a dedicated python module like urllib. Just look for "http request in python" in this website for more information...

Answer (score 0):

The webhook you plan to use is certainly documented with code examples.
If you can find one in Python, it may work from Choregraphe.